# convert list of sparse matrix indices to matrix in R

Tags: r, list, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have this list of strings:

```
dat <- list(V1=c("1:23","4:12"),V2=c("1:3","2:12","6:3"))
```

the list elements V1 and V2 are the columns.
1:23 means "the first entry in this column has value 23".
All other entries should be zero.
The dimension of the matrix is indicated by the highest entry, in this case we have 2 columns (V1 and V2) and the highest row number is a 6, so it would result in a 2x6 matrix like this:

```
matrix(c(23,3,
     0,12,
     0,0,
     12,0,
     0,0,
     0,3),nrow=6,ncol=2,byrow=T)
```

how can this convertion be achieved?

Comment: Did you mean to write `matrix(c(23,3,` ?

Comment: "All other entries are zero" is false, or at best confusing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may also try

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(Matrix)

 d1 <- unnest(dat,col) %>% 
           separate(x, into=c('row', 'val'), ':', convert=TRUE)  %>% 
           extract(col, into='col', '\\D+(\\d+)', convert=TRUE)

 as.matrix(with(d1, sparseMatrix(row, col, x=val)))
 #     [,1] [,2]
 #[1,]   23    3
 #[2,]    0   12
 #[3,]    0    0
 #[4,]   12    0
 #[5,]    0    0
 #[6,]    0    3
```

Comment: `unnest(setNames(dat, seq_along(dat)),col)` is very similar to `stack(dat)`. `as.numeric` works just as well on `ind` in the latter as as on `col` in the former.

Comment: @Frank First, I used `stack` (in the edit), but then thought that people like  `unnest` over `stack` and also using functions mainly from `tidyr/dplyr` makes it more appealing :-)

Comment: Or, actually, `unnest(dat,col)` to keep it in tidyr/dplyr :) No need to rename

Comment: @Frank  But, in the `sparseMatrix`, I need the numeric index.  For example. `d1 <- unnest(dat,col) %>%  separate(x, into=c('row', 'val'), ':', convert=TRUE)`.  I could then use `sub` to extract the numeric part and convert to numeric index

Comment: @Frank made some modification as you suggested.  Does it look good?

Comment: Oh, the problem is that `unnest` behaves according to `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`. This works: `d1 <- stack(dat) %>% separate(values, into=c('row', 'val'), ':', convert=TRUE) %>% mutate(col=as.numeric(ind))`. But this fails: `d1 <- unnest(dat,col) %>% separate(x, into=c('row', 'val'), ':', convert=TRUE) %>% mutate(col=as.numeric(col))`. Sure, looks good :)

Comment: @Frank Thanks for the comment.  In general, the `seq_along` approach may be better if the list names are `xyz', 'vjd' etc. though we can coerce to numeric by specifying the factor levels.

Answer (score 4):

Solution:

```
dat <- list(V1=c("1:23","4:12"),V2=c("1:3","2:12","6:3"))
y <- inverse.rle(list(values = 1:length(dat),lengths = sapply(dat,length)))

x <-  as.numeric(unlist(sapply(dat,function(y)sapply(strsplit(y,":"),function(x)x[1]))))
val <- as.numeric(unlist(sapply(dat,function(y)sapply(strsplit(y,":"),function(x)x[2]))))

num_row <- max(x)
num_col <- max(y) 
m = matrix(0, nrow = num_row, ncol = num_col)
m[cbind(x,y)] <- val
m
```